# Show hidden files in some folders, and not in others

Tags: windows, windows-10

I generally want to see hidden files, in Windows Explorer. Yes, Microsoft seems to think that this is a terrible idea, but then, MS thinks that hiding file extensions is a good idea.

My problem - if I enable `Show hidden files, folders, and drives`, I see two copies of `desktop.ini` on my desktop.

If I recall correctly, in older versions of Windows, you could set these options on a per-folder basis, so I could turn on show hidden files globally, then turn it off in `c:\users\me\desktop`. But it seems to be applied globally.

Is there a way, in Windows 10, to have different settings for this option in different folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mistaken. It was never possible to turn this off per folder.

The only thing you can do is, if folders are not hidden, set the hidden attribute for a file to hide them.

The reason you are seeing 2 desktop.ini files are because there's both your desktop folder and the public users folder. Deleting both files is not something you cannot do, and the one for your folder is likely to come back.

If both come back, it means that some icons that were located in the public folder were physically moved. You can move all these icons from the public desktop folder to all the profiles' desktop folder which should keep the 2nd desktop.ini from reappearing after you delete it.

Comment: Windows XP never showed system files on the desktop, though IIRC they showed up if you looked at the desktop shell folder in an Explorer window.

Comment: @BenN Windows XP had `hide system files` on by default, and also the `show hidden items` was disabled by default. But if my memory serves me correctly, Windows XP did not create a desktop.ini for the desktop anyway.

Comment: I don't think I ever actually checked it, in XP. The dialog where you set it is access through a dialog that provides an option of changing settings for a window or for all windows, and I just assumed.

Comment: @JeffDege Yes, I know what window/button you mean. It only changes things like view. For example, you can have it that one window shows details view, while another one shows large icons view. It does not offer view hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of desktop.ini while still seeing hidden files by making sure "Hide protected operating system files" is checked but leave the other "hide" settings unchecked.

This particular setting will still let you see 99% of hidden files, except for a select few files that you are unlikely to ever need to open such as the hibernation file and the page file on the root of the C drive.

This works in every version of Windows from XP to 10.

Comment: If you want to see the AppData folder, this solution does not work.

Comment: @ajdev8 you may have forgotten to select the "Show hidden files, folders, and drives" radio button. App data isn't a protected system file, so as long as you or some program haven't set that flag on that folder, it should be visible with "Hide protected operating system files" checked. AppData is visible on every computer I use with the option to hide protected system files checked.